# PHP is_nan() not check for a number

Tags: php

It appears that the PHP `is_nan()` function isn't returning anything (not returning `true` or `false`). Here is the code it isn't returning anything in:

```
$id = 111;
$booltest = is_nan($id);
if ($booltest) {
echo 'Invalid ID: "' . $id . '"';
exit();
}
```

It won't fire off the if statement either. I'm using PHP 5. Does anyone know a workaround or way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The expected result of this code is to end silently, since is_nan returns false in that instance.

Comment: Try changing to `$id=NAN`

Comment: The function only returns a compiler warning when set to a string, not the custom error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_nan()` does not check if the data type of the variable is a number or not. There is something called `not a number` or `NaN` which tells us that the number is not in a representable form. `is_nan()` function checks if the number is NaN or not.

If you want to check for integers, you can use `is_int()`.

Like below:

```
$id = 111;
$booltest = is_int($id);
if ($booltest) {
echo 'Invalid ID: "' . $id . '"';
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be conflating [`is_nan`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php) with [`!is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

**[`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)** ("Not a Number") is a specific float value that stands for certain mathematical results that can't be represented by real numbers. For example, the square root of a negative number:

```
$x = sqrt(-1);
var_dump($x);
var_dump(is_nan($x));
var_dump(is_numeric($x));
```

Output:

```
float(NAN)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

`is_nan` only tests floats and only returns `true` for the specific float value NaN. If you give it, say, a string, it will return `null` because the argument is not of float type. So it sounds like you're looking for `is_numeric` instead:

```
$x = "asdf";
var_dump(is_nan($x));
var_dump(is_numeric($x));
$y = 111;
var_dump(is_nan($y));
var_dump(is_numeric($y));
```

Output:

```
NULL
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```